# How to add many UIButtons to UIScrollView in real time with for loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a large array with over 200 items. Each item has an image associated with it. Each image has to be able to be clicked on. I am adding them all as UIButtons to a UIScrollView. For the loop, I have the following code:

```
for (NSString *item in items) {
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(xValue, 0, 70, 70))];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTag:(xValue/75)];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",item]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        xValue += 75;
        [scrollView addSubview:button];
    }
```

This does add the buttons, but I would like that they appear on the view as they are added. Or, if it's possible that the buttons are preloaded before the view even loads, that would be great.

Comment: What do you mean "appear on the view as they are added"? The code you showed should definitely size and add them appropriately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50207703/9137841 refer this.

Comment: With large array over 200 items, you should use tableview or collectionview that resuse button cell. It will be good for your performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to build it this way. You should instead look into using a horizontal `UICollectionView`.

If you do it this way, you'd be loading every image into memory, which can be problematic. By using a collection view, the collection view will only load as many cells as need to be rendered on screen at a given time, reducing your app's memory footprint. It will also set the collection view's content size appropriately.